# ruby/regex getting the first letter of each word

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to get the first letter of each word put together, making something like `"I need help"` turn into `"Inh"`. I was thinking to trim everything off, then going from there, or grab each first letter right away.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could simply use **split**, **map** and **join** together here.

```
string = 'I need help'
result = string.split.map(&:first).join
puts result  #=> "Inh"
```

Comment: Sorry for a dumb question, but what exactly do each part of this do?

Comment: s.split turns it in an array: ['I', 'need', 'help'], map goes through each array chunk taking its first letter. In the end of s.split.map{|w|w[0]} we get ["I", "n", "h"], and .join concatenates it into a pretty and clean string.

Comment: use `string.split(/\W/).map(&:first).join` in Rails to split on every word separate by a non-word character

Comment: I am wondering how this is an accepted solution. I does not work and should not work because there is no method `first` on a `String` object. `'Need'.first` #=> `NoMethodError: undefined method `first' for "Need":String`

Answer (score 7):

How about regular expressions? Using the split method here forces a focus on the parts of the string that you don't need to for this problem, then taking another step of extracting the first letter of each word (chr). that's why I think regular expressions is better for this case. Node that this will also work if you have a `-` or another special character in the string. And then, of course you can add `.upcase` method at the end to get a proper acronym.

`string = 'something - something and something else'`

`string.scan(/\b\w/).join`

`#=> ssase`

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to StackOverflow! While your answer is a valid thought, it would help if you explained why you chose to use regular expressions/why it might be the best/most efficient solution. It would help others understand the line of thinking you took when coming up with your solution, helping them use those same problem solving skills in the future.

Comment: I liked this one better, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution using regex

```
string = 'I need help'
result = string.scan(/(\A\w|(?<=\s)\w)/).flatten.join

puts result
```

This basically says "look for either the first letter or any letter directly preceded by a space". The scan function returns array of arrays of matches, which is flattened (made into one array) and joined (made into a string).

Answer (score 2):

```
string = 'I need help'
result = string.split.map(&:chr).join
puts result
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chr

Comment: You could also use `result = string.split.map(&:chr)*''`